# Compare a property value to an aggregated value in Gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm trying to implement a sort of "window function" in a Gremlin query: I want to select all the edges leaving a vertex, which have a timestamp within 24 hours of the last update (local to the vertex).

For example if User A accessed the following resources:

- Resource 1 at 2019/04/02 23:00
- Resource 2 at 2019/04/02 01:00
- Resource 3 at 2019/04/01 22:00

.. then I'd want the query to return resources 1 & 2, and omit resource 3 because it was accessed 25 hours before User A's latest access (outside the 24-hour window).

I've tried a few different approaches, for example using `local` and `aggregate`:

```
g.V()
  .hasLabel(VertexLabel.User)

  .local(__.outE(EdgeLabel.Accesses) // I also tried "sideEffect" here
    .values(EdgeProperties.UpdateTime).max().math("_ - 24*60*60*1000")
    .aggregate("windowStart"))

  .where(
      __.outE(EdgeLabel.Accesses)
        .has(EdgeProperties.UpdateTime, P.gt("windowStart"))
  )
```

This particular example gives me the error `ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element`.

And also using a `sack`:

```
g.V()
  .hasLabel(VertexLabel.User)

  .sack(Operator.assign).by(
    __.outE(EdgeLabel.Accesses).values(EdgeProperties.UpdateTime).max())
  .sack(Operator.minus).by(__.constant(24*60*60*1000)

  .where(
      __.outE(EdgeLabel.Accesses)
        .not(__.sack().is(P.gt(__.values(EdgeProperties.UpdateTime))))
  )
```

This gives me the error `ClassCastException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`.

I feel like I'm just getting hung up on Gremlin semantics--I'm trying to compare the values in the wrong form. What do I need to do to access the "windowStart" value for the current vertex in the traversal, in a gt/lt predicate?

Comment: Your sample queries start from all users but the description talks about a single user. Do you want the result for one or for multiple users?

Comment: Also, what is the reference for the 24h window? The current time or the time of the last resource access?

Comment: The intention is that the 24 hour window is relative to the latest access for each user, but I'm querying all users at once. So if User A's latest access is Monday, I want to include edges from Sunday for that user. Meanwhile if User B's latest access is Wednesday, I only want to include edges back to Tuesday for that user. I hope that clarifies it, thank you.

Comment: Good, that's what I was guessing. So my answer should be exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few assumptions on what the answers to my comments could be. The following query will give you every user and his respective accessed resources within the last 24 hours (with the reference time being the times of the last resource access time):

```
g.V().hasLabel(VertexLabel.User).
  match(__.as("user").map(outE(EdgeLabel.Accesses).
                          values(EdgeProperties.UpdateTime).max()).
                      math("_-24*60*60*1000").as("m"),
        __.as("user").outE(EdgeLabel.Accesses).
                        where(gt("m")).
                          by(EdgeProperties.UpdateTime).
                          by().
                      inV().fold().as("resources")).
  select("user","resources")
```

Comment: Thanks! I think my main problem was the way I was using the `gt` predicate--I didn't realize you could use the `by` modulators on it--but thanks also for the example using `match` to resolve the timestamp local to the user node.